# Percentage error given the accuracy of two variables (gas law)

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, percentages

> The pressure in an ideal gas is given by $PV = RT$, where $T$ is the temperature of the gas, $V$ is the volume and $R$ is a constant.
>
> Determine the maximum possible percentage error in $P$ when $T$ and $V$ are measured to within an accuracy of $6\%$ and $5\%$ respectively.

My attempt so far:

From the ideal gas law: $P = P(T,V) = \dfrac{RT}{V}$. The differential $\mathrm{d}P$ is given by
$$
dP = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}T}dT + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}V}\mathrm{d}V = \dfrac{R}{V}\mathrm{d}T - \dfrac{RT}{V^2}\mathrm{d}V \;,
$$
so
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}P}{P} = \dfrac{R}{VP}\mathrm{d}T - \dfrac{RT}{V^2P}\mathrm{d}V = \dfrac{R}{V(RT/V)}\mathrm{d}T - \dfrac{RT}{V^2(RT/V)}\mathrm{d}V = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}T}{T} - \dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{V}
$$
and 
$$
\left|\dfrac{\mathrm{d}P}{P}\right| = \left|\dfrac{\mathrm{d}T}{T} - \dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{V}\right| \leq \left|\dfrac{\mathrm{d}T}{T}\right| + \left|\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{V}\right| = 6\% + 5\% = 11\% \;.
$$
After this I draw a blank.

Could someone please fill in the blank and show me what I need to do next? Thanks.

Comment: Where is the blank?? Looks like your answer is 11%

Comment: Why are you using the differential to make an error calculation? The "exact" maximum possible error is given by: $(1-\frac{0.94}{1.05})*100 \approx 10.48\%$

Comment: Notation should be $\delta P, \delta T, \delta V$ not $dP, dT, dV$ and $\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}$ etc for derivatives. Here $\delta P$ represents a small increment in P.

Comment: It looks like I took a completely incorrect approach to the question then, thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your notation tips, I'll bare that in mind :)

Comment: Is it your own question? Why were you trying to use the total differential?

Comment: @ qwertypulipolipohihihehehahahu This is a standard type of linear approximation of maximum error used in physics and engineering. For more complex multivariable problems your exact maximum error may be difficult to compute.